# How to make a tile based map from an array in java?

Tags: java

I've seen it done like this:

```
int[] map =
    {
        1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,

    };
```

In which there would be objects at the position all the 1's are in.
If I make a wall by declaring this:

```
level.add(new Wall(x, y));
```

In which X and Y stand for the tile position, so `level.add(new Wall(0, 0));` will make a wall in the top left, and `level.add(new Wall(20, 15));`will make a wall in the bottom right hand corner.

How can I make it so by having the first value in map to be equal to 1, it will make a wall in the top left corner, and if the last value in map is 1, it will make a wall in the 
bottom right?

Edit: For anyone having having the same problem, here is my solution I I finally used:

```
intro = getAudioClip(getCodeBase(), "intro.wav");
    int[][] map = {
            { 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, },
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, },
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, },
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, },
            { 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, },
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, },
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, },
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, },
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, },
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, },
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, },
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, },
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, },
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, },
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, }

    };

    for (int x = 0; x < map.length; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < map[x].length; y++) {
            if(map[x][y] == 1)
            level.add(new Wall(y, x));
        }
    }
```

Comment: With the way you are thinking about it, you'll need an offset for each row to determine which column is set.  If you want to go with an array-based way of doing this, you should use a multi-dimensional array such as, int[][] map = { {0,0,0}, {1,1,1} };

Comment: But why even use a 1-dimensional array for when a 2-dimensional array would be straightforward?

Comment: I would highly suggest using an enum if you add more tile types beyond Wall and Empty.

Comment: I'll just use different numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a two dimensional array.

```
int[][] map =
{
    {1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
 };
```

Then you can access the position of the array to change values.

```
map[0][0] = 1;
map[15][20] = 1;
```

Answer (score 3):

I see a few decent solutions

Easiest solution:

```
int[][] map = new int[20][15];

// set all to empty
for(int i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < map[0].length; j++) {
        map[i][j] = 0;
    }
}
// make those 2 walls
map[0][0] = 1;
map[1][0] = 1;
```

Better solution

```
class Coordinate {
    final int x;
    final int y;
    Coordinate(int x, int y) { this.x = x ; this.y = y; }
    public int hashCode() { return x >> 16 & y; }
    public boolean equals(Object o) { if (o instanceof Coordinate) { Coordinate c = (Coordinate)o; return c.x==x && c.y==y;} return false; }
}
enum Tile {
    EMPTY,
    WALL,
    TRAP
}

Map<Coordinate,Tile> map = new HashMap<Coordinate,Tile>();
for(int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
    for(int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        map.put(new Coordinate(x,y),Tile.EMPTY);
    }
}

map.put(new Coordinate(0,0), Tile.WALL);
map.put(new Coordinate(0,1), Tile.WALL);
```

Comment: Would it be better to initialize the HashMap with an initial capacity of width * height ? And a load factor that takes into acount, that the the size of the map will never change?

Comment: It's possible you might be able to squeeze some micro-optimization out of it. Performance benefits probably aren't worth the time unless it's 1) in a critical section of code (tight loop, mutex-protected, or something like that) and 2) has incredibly few reads per constructed object.

Answer (score 1):

```
final int width = 20;
final int height = 15;
for(int i = 0; i < width * height; i++) {
    if (map[i] == 1)
        level.add(new Wall(i % width, i / height));
}
```